# should I create database connection everytime for PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, performance

in PHP, I use the following code to get a database connection:

```
$result = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'test');
//...some other code
return $result;
```

My question is, should I create mysqli object every time when connect to the database, if so, will that affect the database performance. Is there any way to save the connection($result) and be reused later?

Thanks.

Comment: you do it once per page load thats it. not every time you run a query

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.persistconns.php

Comment: Create a page like "common.php" and just include it into everyone of you php.pages, so you just have to write it once. there is no way in saving the connection somehow, at least i cant imagine one.

Comment: You mean by Singleton pattern? Yes, you can.

Comment: What you trying to do is performence threat. Databases used to have timeouts to avoid it.

Comment: you can technically create the connection once, and then pass that connection down to whichever object needs it. In a sense you are 'saving' your connection that way. But it is inferior to the 'common.php' concept or dependency injection as a whole. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)

Comment: @viakondratiuk persistent connections are not generally necessary. They may give a marginal improvement but they do come with some gotchas of their own. If you're making so many connections to the DB that you feel you need to persist a connection, it's more than likely you're also transferring huge amounts of data to/from the DB which means the connection is not the bottleneck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should NOT recreate db connection for every query.
If you don't close the connection manually php won't close it until the page request is over.

To keep the connection object you can use a singleton class or a global variable.
 sample for singleton class :

```
class Db
{
    private static $adapter;

    public static function getAdapter()
    {
        if (is_null(self::$adapter)) {
            self::$adapter = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'test');
        }
        return self::$adapter;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

create a class of database connection and call its object where ever you want. doing that you can also create additional methods in that class and assume it as a singleton i give a demo code.

```
// Defination Of Class  DBAccess
class DBAccess
{

    var $username="root";
    var $password="root";
    var $hostname="localhost";
    var $dbname="";

    var $connection = "null";
    var $resultset;
    var $row;
    var $flag;
    var $message;
    var $insertedid;

    function validate()
    {
        echo "John Farnando";
    }

/****************************** START OF CONSTRUCTOR ******************************/
    function DBAccess()
    {
         if(!$this -> connection = mysql_connect( $this -> hostname, $this -> username, $this->password ) )
                $flag = true;
         else if(!mysql_select_db($this->dbname, $this->connection))
                $flag = true;
    }
/****************************** END OF CONSTRUCTOR *******************************/

/****************************** START OF METHOD getFlag *******************************/
    function getFlag()
    {
        if( $flag )
        {
            $flag=false;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
/****************************** END OF METHOD getFlag *******************************/

/****************************** START OF METHOD getConnection *******************************/
    function getConnection()
    {
        return $this -> connection;
    }
/****************************** END OF METHOD getConnection *******************************/

/****************************** START OF METHOD insertRecord *******************************/
    function insertRecord( $query )
    {
        $this -> resultset = mysql_query($query, $this->connection);
        $this -> insertedid = mysql_insert_id();

        if( $this->resultset )
        {
            @mysql_free_result($this->resultset);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            @mysql_free_result($this->resultset);
            return false;
        }
    }
/****************************** END OF METHOD insertRecord *******************************/

/****************************** START OF METHOD getSingleRecord *******************************/
    function getSingleRecord( $query )
    {
        $r = mysql_query ( $query );
        if(@mysql_num_rows($r) > 0)
        {
             return @mysql_fetch_array($r);
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
/****************************** END OF METHOD getSingleRecord *******************************/

/****************************** START OF METHOD getMultipleRecords *******************************/
    function getMultipleRecords( $query )
    {
        $bResult = mysql_query ($query);
        $data = array();
        $index = 0; 
        if(@mysql_num_rows($bResult) >0 )
        {       
            while ( $row = @mysql_fetch_array($bResult) )
            {
                //echo mysql_error();
                $data[$index] = $row;
                $index++;
            }
            //echo "<br />It comes here In While Loop<br />";
             return $data;
        }
        else
        {
            //echo "<br />It comes here In eLSE cASe in Query<br />";
            return false;
        }
    }
/****************************** END OF METHOD getSingleRecord *******************************/

/****************************** START OF DELETE FUNCTION ***********************************/
    function deleteRecord( $query )
    {
        if(($bResult = mysql_query ($query))==FALSE) 
        {
            return false;
        }   
        return true;
    }

/******************************  END  OF  FUNCTION DELETE **************************************/

/******************************  START OF FUNCTION UPDATE **************************************/
    function updateRecord( $query )
    {
        if(($bResult = mysql_query ($query))==FALSE)
        {
            return false;
        }   
        return true;
    }

/****************************** END OF FUNCTION UPDATE **************************************/

/******************************  START OF FUNCTION getNewId *********************************/
    function getNewId()
    {
        return $this->insertedid;
    }
/****************************** END OF FUNCTION getNewId **************************************/

}   //  End of class DBAccess
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a file connection.php, and in that declare the connection variable. Include connection.php on top of every page, or in the header file.

Comment: Your solution is practical but it's procedural. A singleton pattern for the database connection is more OOP. It's a cleaner approach.